# Will Microsoft 365 fail new Gmail "Email sender guidelines" re: reverse DNS check?

Tags: email, gmail, microsoft-365

Gmail recently published new "**Email sender guidelines**" which will be enforced from February 2024. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126

In "**Requirements for all senders**" it says "*Ensure that sending domains or IPs have valid forward and reverse DNS records, also referred to as PTR records*".

I did a test email from Microsoft 365 to https://www.mail-tester.com and it complains that "*Your reverse DNS does not match with your sending domain*".

```
Your IP address 40.107.108.77 is associated with the domain mail-me3aus01on2077.outbound.protection.outlook.com.
Nevertheless your message appears to be sent from AUS01-ME3-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com.
```

I also found this Microsoft article which seems to suggest that Microsoft knowingly don't support this requirement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/exchange/troubleshoot/antispam-and-protection/cannot-send-emails-to-external-recipients

Does this mean that Gmail may start rejecting emails from Microsoft 365 starting February 2024, or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test failure you quote seems to be about something different than just the reverse DNS requirement listed in the Gmail guidelines. Maybe HELO/EHLO mismatch compared to reverse DNS, which is what the linked Microsoft article seems to be about?
You can probably drill down in the details of the test results to confirm what exactly failed.

Anyway, `40.107.108.77` in your example does have forward-confirmed reverse DNS in place, which is the requirement you quoted from the Gmail guidelines.

```
$ dig -x 40.107.108.77 +short
mail-me3aus01on2077.outbound.protection.outlook.com.
$ dig mail-me3aus01on2077.outbound.protection.outlook.com. +short
40.107.108.77
$
```

Unless the unconfirmed specifics of that test failure you saw is also something that is listed somewhere in the Gmail guidelines (I did not see HELO/EHLO alignment listed, fwiw), then this all seems like a non-issue in terms of complying with the Gmail guidelines. (While still suboptimal in terms of more general best practices)

Answer (score 1):

`Does this mean that Gmail may start rejecting emails from Microsoft 365 starting February 2024?`

No. Microsoft 365 has over 500 million email user mailboxes. Gmail will make accommodations for the largest providers.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that Gmail may start rejecting emails from Microsoft
> 365 starting February 2024, or have I misunderstood something?

By the strict "letter of the law" they might, but it's doubtful they'd start blocking email from a provider that hosts emails for somewhere in the neighborhood of 500 million mailbox users.

What you should do to ensure the best chances of your email deliverability is make sure you have properly configured SPF, DKIM, and DMARC for your emails.